# Determine the natural filtration of a given stochastic process

Tags: solution-verification, stochastic-differential-equations, filtrations

Let $\Omega=\{\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\omega_4\}$ and $X=\{X_t\}_{t=0,1,2}$, where
$$X(0)=3, X(1,\omega)=\begin{cases}5, \omega=\omega_1,\omega_2 \\ 2, \omega=\omega_3,\omega_4 \end{cases}, X(2,\omega)=\begin{cases}6, \omega=\omega_1,\omega_2 \\ 3, \omega=\omega_3 \\ 3, \omega=\omega_4 \end{cases}.$$

1. Find the natural filtration of $X$, i.e., find $\mathcal{F}_0^x=\sigma(X(0))$, $\mathcal{F}_1^x=\sigma(X(0),X(1))$, and $\mathcal{F}_2^x=\sigma(X(0),X(1),X(2))$.
2. Find the conditional expectation $E[X(2)\mid \mathcal{F}_1^x]$.

**Attempt:**

1. We have to find $\sigma(X(0))$,$\sigma(X(1))$, and $\sigma(X(2))$.

First of all, I don't know what the meaning of $X(0)=3$ is.
Does the value of $X(0)$ matter? I think that it doesn't matter, since at time $t=0$, we are told nothing about the events, and so
$\sigma(X(0))=\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$.

Furthermore,

$\sigma(X(1))=\{\emptyset, \Omega, \{\omega_1,\omega_2\}, \{\omega_3,\omega_4\}\}$,

$\sigma(X(2))=\{\emptyset, \Omega, \{\omega_1,\omega_2\}, \{\omega_3,\omega_4\}\}$.

Hence,

$\mathcal{F}_0^x=\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$,

$\mathcal{F}_1^x= \sigma(X(1))$,

$\mathcal{F}_2^x= \sigma(X(1))$.

2. Let $A_1=\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}$ and $A_2=\{\omega_3,\omega_4\}$ be the set of events in $X(2)$.
   Then,
   $$E[X(2) \mid A_1]= \frac{6 \cdot \frac14+6\cdot \frac14}{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}}= 6$$
   and
   $$E[X(2) \mid A_2]= \frac{3 \cdot \frac14+3\cdot \frac14}{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}}= 3$$,
   so
   $$E[X(2) \mid \mathcal{F}_1^x]= 
   \begin{cases}
   6, \omega=\omega_1,\omega_2 \\
   3, \omega=\omega_3,\omega_4
   \end{cases}.$$

Am I correct? Any help please? Many thanks in advanced.

Comment: Part 1 looks correct. Part 2. What was the silent assumption on the unconditional probabilities of $\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\omega_4$ ?

Comment: @KurtG. What about the $X(0)=3$?

Comment: @KurtG. The assumption is they are have the same probability.

Comment: Then Part 2 looks correct. Question : can a deterministic value for $X(0)$ have any influence on the natural filtration of $X$ ?

Comment: @KurtG. The answer is no?

Comment: You are guessing . Hint : what is the difference between the $\sigma$-algebras generated by a RV $X$ and $X$ shifted by a constant $c$ . Hint : Those "two" $\sigma$-algebras are generated by the sets $\{X\le x\}$ and $\{X+c\le x\}$ . And besides of that . In your specific example: the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the constant $X(0)$ is what ? What is it if you change that constant to another constant ?

Comment: @KurtG. There is no difference. Could you answer please? I'm in confusing.

Comment: There is no difference.